# Incomplete FTP transfers with Yosemite (Transmit & FileZilla)

Tags: macos, data-transfer, ftp

I'm having weird issues when uploading files via FTP. I'm not entirely sure, but I think I never observed this problem before using OS X 10.10:

File uploads via FTP in both FileZilla and Transmit are often and non-reproducibly incomplete. Text files just end somewhere in the middle of a line, yet both FTP clients report successful transfers. The next time I try uploading a file it might either just work or it might be chopped at a different position. It seems entirely random.

This does not seem to happen with SFTP connections. Also, I successfully uploaded the very same upload queue to the same server using FileZilla on a Windows machine – without any problem.

I wonder if somebody has had similar issues or even a solution.

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: Did you have the filezille/transmit app allready on you hd prior to upgrading to 10.10? Perhaps deleting and reinstallong could solve the issue. I didn't have the problem with an ftp client but with another app and this is how i solved the problem

Answer (score -2):

Same problem but with cyberduck, tested on multiple computers and to various ftp servers. For now I've resorted to the upload options in cpanel which works fine, but that is not a good solution.